# Find the save ID where rows deleted from the previous save within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following table has a particular SaveID, 
 
in SaveID(5) 1 row is added. 
 
in SaveID(9) another row is added so my RowNb = 1 and 2 
 
in SaveID(11) same rows 1 and 2 are saved. 
 
in SaveID(17) row 2 is missing 
 
Only insert operation is performed, no update or delete.

```
    SaveID       RowNb
    5               1
    9               1
    9               2
    11              1
    11              2
    17              1
```

```
DECLARE @MyLogs Table(SaveID int, RowNb int, ColVal nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO  @MyLogs (SaveID, RowNb, ColVal) VALUES (5,1,'Val1');
INSERT INTO  @MyLogs (SaveID, RowNb, ColVal) VALUES (9,1,'Val1');
INSERT INTO  @MyLogs (SaveID, RowNb, ColVal) VALUES (9,2,'Val2');
INSERT INTO  @MyLogs (SaveID, RowNb, ColVal) VALUES (11,1,'Val1');
INSERT INTO  @MyLogs (SaveID, RowNb, ColVal) VALUES (11,2,'Val22');
INSERT INTO  @MyLogs (SaveID, RowNb, ColVal) VALUES (17,1,'Val1');

Select SaveID, Count(RowNb) cntRows 
From @MyLogs  
group by SaveID
order by SaveID
```

I want the SaveID where the cntRows < cntRows of the previous SaveID.

And I'm searching for the missing rows from the previous save.  
 
The query should return the SaveID = 17
If possible with the RowNb from the previous record and val. 
 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh: MS SQL Server.

Comment: Logically, if 17 should be returned then 5 should be returned as well. Both have no "prior" so that doesn't match your description. It sounds like you want to count the rows for each SaveID and compare that number to the max value of RowNb for SaveID. But there are many assumptions inherent in that goal. What would happen if (5, 3) and (5, 4) existed? You need to provide more detail. Don't over simplify your sample data.

Comment: @SMor Exactly I want to count the rows for each SaveID and compare when the rowNb becomes less than the previous SaveID. The SaveID is NOT sequential but always in Ascending order. (There is no delete operation on that table, ONLY Insert) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server: OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DELETE Sales.ShoppingCartItem  
    OUTPUT DELETED.*;
```

Comment: Thanks @shoek but  this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

As for the sql, [WITH expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [RANK function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) might be of help.

(not tested)

```
WITH rw (SaveID, RowNb, ord)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT SaveID, RowNb, RANK(SaveID) OVER (ORDER BY SaveID ASC) AS ord
    FROM @MyLogs
    -- WHERE ...
)
SELECT crnt.SaveID, crnt.RowNb
FROM rw AS prev
LEFT OUTER JOIN rw AS crnt
ON prev.ord = crnt.ord - 1 AND prev.RowNb = crnt.RowNb
WHERE crnt.RowNb IS NULL
ORDER BY crnt.SaveID, prev.RowNb
```

As a matter of design, note that

- At least one row must be inserted on every save. (e.g. If your application allows to remove all rows on save, it may not.)
- The greatest `SaveID` must be assigned on the last save. (e.g. If `SaveID` is a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with `CYCLE`, it may not.)
- It is memory/time-consuming to calculate `RANK()`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help, because SaveID is not sequential, I'm also looking when the previous RowNb count > current RowNb count